# How to rename column with using paste() function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have df like this:

```
df <- data.frame (var1  = c(12,56,23),
                  var2 = c(12,12,34))
```

How can I rename the first column with `paste()` function?

```
x <- "USD"

df %>% rename(paste(x,"varNEW") = var1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `setNames` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rename(setNames("var1", paste(x, "varNEW", sep = "_")))
#>   USD_varNEW var2
#> 1         12   12
#> 2         56   12
#> 3         23   34
```

or using the special assignment operator `:=`:

```
df %>% 
  rename("{x}_varNEW" := var1)
#>   USD_varNEW var2
#> 1         12   12
#> 2         56   12
#> 3         23   34
```

Comment: How can I rename multiple column where? df %>% 
  rename(setNames("var1", paste(x, "varNEW", sep = "_")))

Comment: Simply use vectors, e.g. `x <- c("USD", "EUR"); df %>% rename(setNames(c("var1", "var2"), paste(x, "varNEW", sep = "_")))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename_with` function:

```
x <- "USD"

df %>%
  rename_with(~paste(x,"varNEW"),
              .cols = var1)
```

Output:

```
  USD varNEW var2
1         12   12
2         56   12
3         23   34
```

Comment: how can I rename multiple columns?

Comment: Just gave the columns names you want to change to `.cols` argument: `.cols = c(var1,var2)`. But make sure your function create differents names: `rename_with(~paste(x,"varNEW",.),
              .cols = c(var1,var2))`

Answer (score 0):

In **Base R**

```
x <- "USD"
names(df)[1] <- paste(x , "varNew")
```

If you want to rename other columns

```
x <- c("USD1" , "USD2")
names(df) <- paste(x , "varNew")
```